# How reliable are unix domain sockets?

Tags: linux, sockets, ipc, reliability

I'm trying to figure out a protocol to use with domain sockets and can't find information on how blindly the domain sockets can be trusted.

Can data be lost? Are messages always received in the same order as sent? Even when using datagram sockets?

Are transfers atomic? When reading the socket, can I trust that I get the whole message on one read or do I have to check it myself?

Answer (score 13):

From 'man AF_UNIX':

Valid  types  are:  SOCK_STREAM,  for  a  stream-oriented  socket   and
SOCK_DGRAM,  for  a  datagram-oriented  socket  that  preserves message
boundaries (**as on most Unix implementations, Unix domain datagram sockets
are always reliable and don’t reorder datagrams**);